# Setting delay time in javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft'); 
    var objDiv = document.querySelector("._5tee .uiScrollableAreaWrap");
    var n = -1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (n == el.length) 
        {
            break;
        }   
        else
        {
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
         n = el.length;
         var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft'); 
    }
```

This code is about one div box with a scroll bar. When the code is being executed it goes down to the last item and then the box loads more items but the code stops cause the box needs some ms to load the other items.

So i want you to help me make one delay time with setTimeout or setInterval
and when it has no more items to load, the while loop will stop.

What would you suggest to use, setTimeout or setInterval???
And what should the code be like???
i only want the scroll down( `objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;` ) to run every 3ms (for example)
could you help me with that??

Comment: I would suggest putting a check between `if (n == el.length) { //checlk here; break; }`

Comment: It can't be done without a function, because Javascript will block until the script executes and the page will not get updated untill then. setTimeout or setInterval is the way to go, and they both need a function as the first argument. Another possible way is to reload the script, but I won't recomment doing it like that. If you want a delay in your while loop, it is possible but the page will not get updated. For that just use the Date object and compare to a previous date plus the millisecs delay.

Comment: @JuanGarcia could you help me with the function then? give me and example

Comment: @cyber_rookie to check what?? the timeout??

Comment: @torazaburo - yes, a space-delimited list of classes to search for is supporeted by getElementsByClassName: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: @PeterLillevold thanks for the comment! could anyone now suggest what can i do so the code to have a delay?!?!? :)

Comment: @SteliosM. - what have you tried so far? Please show due effort first, and ask questions when any issue arises, lest your question will be closed. Good to read before asking in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PeterLillevold ok i will update in some hours with anything that i have tried until now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hereYouGo() {
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft'); 
    var objDiv = document.querySelector("._5tee .uiScrollableAreaWrap");
    var n = -1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (n == el.length) 
        {
            break;
        }   
        else
        {
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
         n = el.length;
         var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft'); 
    }


    }
var myTimer = setInterval(hereYouGo, 1000);
```

try this code here im pretty sure that it will work.

Comment: thanks man it seems that it didnt have to be with "no function" at all :)